# Header design for electronics store

Tags: website-design, branding

I have to make a header for this store that sells Alarms, CCTV and others electronics stuff, the thing is that I cant find a design that matches with their logo.[image: header with logo and nav centered]

[image: nav left]

I spent several days trying to make something that matches and this is the best I could come up with. Still, have that bad feeling that something is wrong, or that could be better, the truth is that I'm running out of time and can't figure out something better.

Any Ideas?

Comment: The angles of the navigation buttons make little visual sense.

Comment: Their logo has some angle but at the same time is very sharp, so I tried to keep the same "style", I guess I failed lol.

Comment: The logo doesn't have *enough* of an angle to merit other elements repeating that angle. The A is rarely read as an "angle" specifically. It's read as type.. a glyph... not the same as an actual block or shape. And, that is the sole location... to me, just not enough to merit the repeat. (But I knew you were going to post that :) )

Comment: Just my opinion, I could be wrong -- squint and look at the logo.. it appears as a block, the angle isn't very prominent.

Comment: I don't see why your design should match the logo. Look at a few strong brand websites, do any of them have such a stylised menu? A header/menu should be functional and I don't see the slanted menu item add anything, functionally or visually.

Comment: Requested by the client, the whole website needs to match the logo, and as a special requirement the header needs to be very visually impacting, always with an air of the company.@JaneDoe1337

Comment: Ok so this got closed — but questions like this one are ok over at https://usability.testing.exchange. You might want to post your question over there. It's a website & design feedback place, where you give feedback to others, and then get feedback about your own stuff — as much as you gave to others. (I'm developing it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would:

- make the entire header's background blue, with the logo and menu in white text.
- if the above isn't possible (logo/branding restrictions), make the entire navbar blue with white text.
- make the menu row fix to top when scrolling down.
- make the the entire menu row taller, collapsing to a smaller height when switching to the top-fixed layout.
- display their logo on the top-anchored menu, floated to the leftmost.
- use all-caps for the menu row texts.
- perhaps make the active item on the menu row italic.
- find the font on bottom of their logo (the part that says "ELECTRONICA") and use that logo on a significant amount of elements throughout the site.
- experiment with centering their logo, especially on larger screens.

As an aside, do check out [dribbble](https://www.dribbble.com), [behance](https://www.behance.net/), [awwwards](https://www.awwwards.com/websites/) or some other source for inspiration. Perhaps you can find a layout you can mimic that works well with their logo, products, and services offered.